# git - ignoring a folder locally without any changes on remote when committing

Tags: git, gitignore, ignore

Through my research, I have seen people asking for how to keep a folder locally and delete it on the remote, and vice-versa. But I'm having a subtler issue. Sorry if it happens that I've not searched enough.

Hello, I use IntelliJ IDEA to work on a project that is made for Eclipse (I dislike Eclipse that much). Nevertheless, there is a .idea folder on the remote for compatibility reasons. The thing is, it should stay as-is on the remote. Because I'm using IntelliJ, it's consistently getting updated by myself.

Some parts of it are ignored and don't show up in commits (e.g the dependency .xml files created by Gradle import), but files like my workspace.xml are ignored in .gitignore, but the ignore doesn't "register", meaning that they're ignored, yet they are included in commits. That's just because they existed already when I ignored them.

So what I want to do is to make it so all files in the .idea folder actually get ignored (don't show up in commits), but **without having to actually delete them from either the index or the file system**. Right now, if I use the "usual" methods, they include doing `git rm --cached -r folder`. If I do that, it shows up as a deletion when committing, and I just want to make it so all changes are ignored without any noticeable change on commit history (e.g deletion).

Hoping I was clear enough, thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `.git/info/exclude` and add the `.idea` folder. The syntax for this file is the same as `.gitignore`.

This approach allows you to let git ignore files locally without the need to add them to a remote `.gitignore`.